# Nested slidebox in ionic

Tags: nested, ionic-framework, slide

I have a slidebox and in one slide, I have some content and one more slidebox. If I slide on content main slidebox should slide. If I slide on second slidebox, inner slides should slide.

But now, If I slide on inner slidebox, both the slideboxes are sliding.

I need to stop main slidebox sliding while inner slidebox is sliding. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Some options: create individual controllers for each slide, use different eventHandler method names (if possible!). Sorry still very new to Ionic myself!

Answer (score 0):

You prevent a parent ion-slide-box from "sliding" by using `on-touch/release` events in the child combined with the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` service.

First you need to give your parent `<ion-slide-box>` a `delegate-handle`. Then you can capture the `on-touch` and `on-release` events on the child slider, to pin the parent and stop it from sliding.

Like this:

```
<ion-slide-box delegate-handle="parent-slider" class="parent">
  <ion-slide>
      <h2>Parent</h2>

        <ion-slide-box class="child">
            <ion-slide
                on-touch="pinParent()"
                on-release="unpinParent()">

                  <h3>Child</h3>
              </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Then in your controller, you can add two simple functions to freeze the parent slide-box from moving when the child slide-box is being touched.

Like so:

```
$scope.pinParent = function () {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('parent-slider').enableSlide(false)
}

$scope.unpinParent = function () {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('parent-slider').enableSlide(true)
}
```

Here is a CodePen example: http://codepen.io/F1LT3R/pen/jBarQe